# Example for kernel timer Implementation in Linux (in kernel 2.6.32)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Could you please give any basic example of a kernel timer (`start_ktimer`) implementation in Linux?

Comment: Are you wondering how to use kernel timers or how the kernel timers are implemented

Comment: I just to want to use the kernel timer in my own kernel module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can tell, Linus never incorporated the [ktimer patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/152435/) into the main line of development. Note that the patch does contain examples of using start_ktimer (see fs/exec.c).
If you specifically want to use [ktimers](http://lwn.net/Articles/152436/), you will need to port the patch circa kernel version 2.6.13 forward to the 2.6.32 kernel.

On the other hand, if all you need is a timer mechanism, the standard kernel timer API may work. For a good discussion of how to use this API as well as examples, see [Chapter 7](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf) of the Linux Device Drivers book, specifically, the section titled "The Timer API" (page 198). In this case, the equivalent of `start_ktimer()` is `add_timer()`.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://hardikmadhu.blogspot.in/2013/11/timer-interrupt-in-linux-kernel.html) is an example... :) Simple and easy... Source code available:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <asm/param.h>

struct timer_list exp_timer;

static void do_something(unsigned long data)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Your timer expired and app has been called\n");       
}

static int __init tst_init(void)
{       
        int delay = 300;

        printk(KERN_INFO "Init called\n");

        init_timer_on_stack(&exp_timer);

        exp_timer.expires = jiffies + delay * HZ;
        exp_timer.data = 0;
        exp_timer.function = do_something;

        add_timer(&exp_timer);

        return 0;
}

static void __exit tst_exit(void)
{       
        del_timer(&exp_timer);  
        printk(KERN_INFO "Exit called\n");
}

module_init(tst_init);
module_exit(tst_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```